# Use Excel formulae results in array for nested function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

In Excel, is it possible to have multiple formulae slot together into an array for a nested function?

Consider

```
=SMALL({10\15\20\25\30},1)
```

The formula returns the smallest value in the array. Now I'm trying to do something similar but not with a static array but something like this:

```
=SMALL({VLOOKUP($A$1,$A$2:$C$11,2)\VLOOKUP($A$1,$A$2:$C$11,3)\VLOOKUP($A$1,$A$2:$C$11,4)},1)
```

But that does not work unfortunately.

Comment: Google `array formula`

Comment: Why don't you use `min`? `=min(VLOOKUP($A$1,$A$2:$C$11,2),VLOOKUP($A$1,$A$2:$C$11,3),VLOOKUP($A$1,$A$2:$C$11,4))`

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I did look at that but it was still unclear to me if I could combine function results in an array for further calculation.

Comment: @MátéJuhász actually for the time being that is good solution, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first formula works because it is using an **array constant** properly.

An array constant is a simple list of numbers or strings enclosed in curly brackets like:

```
 {1,2,3,4}
```

The following expressions will **not** work:

```
{1,2,3,4+1}
{A1,B3,C9}
{SUM(A1:B9),SUM(T7:T9)}
```

So if we have:

[image]

and we want to use `SMALL()` then enter:

```
=VLOOKUP($A$1,$A$2:$D$11,2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP($A$1,$A$2:$D$11,3,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP($A$1,$A$2:$D$11,4,FALSE)
```

In **F4** through **H4** respectively and then we can use:

```
=SMALL(F4:H4,1)
```

[image]

Comment: I see, This is quite unfortunate as I was hoping to combine `INDEX` to find all instances of an item in a table and return the corresponding components required, to feed  a `VLOOKUP` to to find component requirement and availability for an item and determine how many items can be built depending on the constraining component availability. But as demonstrated by you, this seems impossible without a step in between.

Comment: @SilentRevolution  Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, I already have the `{=ROUNDDOWN(VLOOKUP(INDEX(ComponentRequirement;SMALL(IF(ComponentRequirement[Type]=[@Type];ROW(ComponentRequirement[Type]));1)-31;2);ComponentAvailability;3;FALSE)/INDEX(ComponentRequirement;SMALL(IF(ComponentRequirement[Type]=[@Type];ROW(ComponentRequirement[Type]));1)-31;3);0)}` which finds the first, component (change `k` in the `SMALL` to find component 2 and 3), and that could feed into the table, in columns `Component1\Component2\Component3` and then use the three cells for the last `SMALL` Function to find the constraining component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array constant in place of the `VLOOKUP` **column index number**, e.g.

`=SMALL(VLOOKUP($A$1,$A$2:$D$11,{2\3\4}),1)`

This is an "array formula" that needs to be confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Another way with `INDEX` and `MATCH`.....

`=SMALL(INDEX($B$2:$D$11,MATCH($A$1,$A$2:$A$11),0),1)`

Needs just "normal" entry